# Definition of ionisation energy

Tags: everyday-chemistry

My lecturer has defined ionization energy or ionization potential of a species A as the molar internal energy change, ΔU, for the reaction: $\ce{A (g) -> A+ (g) + e-}$ at $\pu{0 K}$, with reactants and products being in their standard states.

How can reactants and products be in their standard states when they must be gaseous?!

He then goes on to say that we often assume  $\Delta U (\pu{0 K})\approx \Delta H (\pu{298 K})$. I presume he means that the molar internal energy change of the above process at $\pu{0 K}$ is approximately equal to the enthalpy change of the above process at $\pu{298 K}$? Why is this approximation valid?

Comment: I am wondering how some teachers can teach simple topics in a dry, complicated and "bookish" way. https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Inorganic_Chemistry/Map%3A_Inorganic_Chemistry_(Housecroft)/02%3A_Basic_concepts%3A_molecules/2.4%3A_The_Octet_Rule_and_Isoelectronic_Species/24.D%3A_Periodic_Trends. They explain it here "This energy change is generally considered equivalent to the enthalpy change at 298 K (ΔH298 K). Estimates of the error suggest < 10 kJmol-1 which when compared to typical IE values often in their thousands, is insignificant."

Answer (score 1):

It is common practice to define the standard state of a gas when describing its thermodynamic properties. For instance, the free energy of an ideal gas can be defined relative to the free energy in its standard state (the gas at a partial pressure of 1 bar and at the same temperature), as

$$G = G^\circ + RT\log\left( \frac{p}{p^\circ} \right)$$

where $p^\circ= \pu{1 bar}$.

In practice it may be impossible to achieve the gaseous state described in the OP, not least because absolute zero is not experimentally accessible. However, there are workarounds that might allow one to extrapolate to $\pu{0 K}$ and to standard conditions (a pressure of 1 bar). First the easy part, the pressure: if you have a very dilute gas, then intermolecular interactions become unimportant in describing its behavior, it becomes practically *ideal*. As such, its behavior at any other pressure can be described by using standard equations applicable to ideal gases. It does not matter that the state described is not real, it can be used as a *hypothetical* reference point. For instance, if we know the free energy under ideal gas conditions at a particular pressure, we can compute the free energy in the standard state as follows:

$$G^\circ = G - RT\log\left( \frac{p}{p^\circ} \right)$$

For an ideal gas, the internal energy $U$ is independent of pressure, so in the given example there is no need to perform any computation at all, provided we are at the right T. The problem is of course that we are not at the right T. In practice it may be possible to either assume that the experiment was conducted sufficiently close to $T=\pu{0 K}$, so that we can assume the equality holds, or to extrapolate to that temperature by performing experiments over a range of T.

As for the approximation $\Delta U (\pu{0 K})\approx \Delta H (\pu{298 K})$, I'll give a roundabout justification, since I am not an expert on the subject. There are two points that can be made. First, it is probably ok to assume $\Delta U (\pu{0 K})\approx \Delta U (\pu{298 K})$ if it can be assumed that the electronic transition is not sensitive to differences in the distribution of (mainly vibrational) thermal motions at $\pu{0 K}$ and $\pu{298 K}$.

Second, $$\Delta H = \Delta U + \Delta (pV) = \Delta U + \Delta n RT $$ However here we have a conundrum. The reported IE ignores the kinetic energy of the electron (it assumes that the emitted electron has no kinetic energy). But the thermodynamic expression assumes thermal equilibrium, so which is it? Well, at zero Kelvin there is no translational energy, so when considering $\Delta U(\pu{0 K})$ we can safely ignore any thermal contribution from the electron. So we are ignoring the thermal properties of the released electron, and then since $\Delta n =0$ (ignoring the electron) we have that $$\Delta H = \Delta U$$